# Non-linear regression with vectors as observations

Tags: r, nonlinear-regression

I'm blocking on a computational problem, that is fitting a function

$\begin{array}{lrcl}
f_{\alpha} : & \mathbb{R}^k & \longrightarrow & \mathbb{R} \end{array}$ to observations $(x_1, ..., x_n)$ that are vectors of $\mathbb{R^{m_{i}}}$ (the length of each vector is different, so that each $x_i \in \mathbb{R^{m_{i}}}$). In the following reprex my function is defined as 
$f_{\alpha}(x) = (\sum_{i = 1}^n x_i^{\alpha}$). I'm getting a type error, and I don't really know how to handle it. 
Thank you by advance

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)

dummy_fun <- function(x, alpha){
  return(sum((x)^alpha))
}



set.seed(123)
dummy_data <-
  data_frame(id =  c(rep(c(1:8), times = c(10,12,8,13,7,8,10,12))), x = runif(80)) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  nest() %>%
  mutate(y = map_dbl(data, dummy_fun, alpha = 2)) %>%
  rename(obs = data)

nls.test <- nls(y ~ dummy_fun(x = obs, alpha), data = dummy_data, start = list(alpha = 1.5))
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to deal with a variable-sized real vector of inputs?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/213955/how-to-deal-with-a-variable-sized-real-vector-of-inputs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not check the dplyr code but I noticed that the dummy_data table contains tibbles  (column obs). I also encountered problems with the nls function, then I decided to use a different strategy. Below you will find a small R code.

There are 2 differences w.r.t your attempt.

1. I defined a function dummy_fun2 which sapply trough each element of the dplyr column obs
2. I used the the optimize function for the estimaiton task.

I left some comments in my code as guide. 
Hope my answer will help you.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)

# Original piece of code---
dummy_fun <- function(x, alpha){
  return(sum((x)^alpha))
}

set.seed(123)
dummy_data <-
  data_frame(id =  c(rep(c(1:8), times = c(10,12,8,13,7,8,10,12))), x = runif(80)) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  nest() %>%
  mutate(y = map_dbl(data, dummy_fun, alpha = 2)) %>%
  rename(obs = data)
# End original piece of code ---

# Modified dummy function - sum(x^alpha) on each element of the cell 
dummy_fun2 = function(x, alpha){
  out = sapply(x, function(x) sum((x)^alpha))
  return(out)
}

# Obj function to be minimize
optFun = function(theta)
{
  # if needed keep pars > 0 alpha = exp(theta)
  alpha = theta

  # Mu (a vector) and rss
  mu = dummy_fun2(x = dummy_data$obs, alpha)
  res = dummy_data$y - mu
  sum(res^2)
}

# Optimization task
nls.test = optimize(f = optFun, interval = c(-5, 5))
(nls.test$minimum)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. It's helping me, even if I'll have to adapt the code to my real problem, but I'm wondering why you're defining the loglike as the sum dnorm(dummy_data$y, mu, sig, log = T) (my main concern is about the normal distribution)
EDIT: you maximise the sum of the dnorm because of the hypothesis of the non-linear model ? (Gaussian observations etc. )

Comment: Hi actually that was my own hypothesis indeed. My interest was more focused on the definition dummy_fun2. Im my updated answer now I minimize the residual sum of squares (I think this was your original intention)

Comment: I really like your idea, I'll try to apply it on my concrete problem ! :) Thank you

Comment: Happy to help. Consider to accept the answer if you realize it is appropriate ^_^